# Socket android framework doesn't send message

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to add a client socket in the file ViewRootImpl.java. I'm creating the socket in a new thread with an handler because I need to comunicate between threads. I'm sending a message to Vthread every time performTraversal is called.

Client code in ViewRootImpl.java:

```
public class Vthread extends Thread{

    Viewhandler mViewhandler;
    Handler mhandler;

    Socket client;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String s;
    String line;

    Vthread(Viewhandler handler){
        mViewhandler = handler;
        in = null;
        out = null;
        s = "hello";
        client = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Looper.prepare();

        try{

            client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 60000);
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
       }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
        mhandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                try{
                    if(out != null && in != null && client != null){
                        out.println(s);
                        out.flush();

                        line = in.readLine();
                    }
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }};

        Looper.loop();

    }

}
```

The server code in the host:

```
Socket socket;
ServerSocket server;
SocketAddress sockaddr;
BufferedReader in = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
String line;                
String s = "bye";
server = null;

try{
    sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 60000);
    server = new ServerSocket();
    server.bind(sockaddr);

    socket = server.accept();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
    System.out.println("connected");
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);


        out.println(s);
    }
    if (server != null ) server.close();

}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The connection is accepted but the server doesn't receive any message from client. A problem that I identified is that more than one process might be using the socket. So I used a file in the internal storage of my application to restric the socket to my application only, but the problem remains. Code to restrict the socket to my application:

```
if(mVthread.mhandler != null) {
    try{
        if(reader == null) reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.arg1 = 1000;
        mVthread.mhandler.sendMessage(msg);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that the client socket sends a message but the server doesn't receive it. Both sides are blocked in the receive function. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?